# Type mismatch: inferred type is unit but int is expected kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Im trying to get multiple types of return (Int and Boolean) but i can only seem to get one at a time:

```
fun isValidPositions(p1: Int, p2: Int, pairs: List<Char>):Boolean{
    if(p1 !in 0..9 || p2 !in 0..9 ){
        println("Posições inválidas")
    }else if (p1 == p2){
        println("Posições inválidas")
    }else if(pairs.get(p1) != '_' || pairs.get(p2) != '_' )
        println("Posições inválidas")
    return true
}
```

then in my funcion main i have this:

```
 val first = readPosition("primeira")
        val second = readPosition("segunda")
        if ( isValidPositions(first, second, places) ) {
            places = places.play(first, second, pairs)
```

and it gives me the error: Type mismatch: inferred type is unit but int is expected
i cant seem to understand how i can get 2 types of return when i need the true and an int
im really new to coding since i just got into uni

Comment: What line is the error on?  I don't see any return in the second block, so there is probably some details missing.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely that `readPosition` doesn't return anything (in Kotlin, that means returning `Unit`). This means that you're assigning `Unit` to your `first` and `second` variables instead of the `Int` value you're expecting.

Then when you reach `isValidPositions`, it wants an `Int` but you're passing `Unit`.

You should post your `readPosition` function to get more help on this.